# In C++ is there a way to call a function with a std::stringstream& argument without the caller using a named variable?

Tags: c++, stringstream

In C++, is it possible to call a function whose argument is std::stringstream& without the caller declaring an explicit named variable of type std::stringstream?

I.e. I would like to accomplish something along the lines of this:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func("Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");

  return 0;
}
```

The above code generates this compile error:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.c:11:23: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [13]’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<<’
   11 |   func("Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~
      |        |
      |        const char [13]
```

(I'm not sure if I properly understand the problem -- I think it is because the `const char*` "Hello World" is not implicitly cast to anything for which the `<<` operator is applicable -- is that correct?)

I tried this next:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func(std::stringstream("Hello World ") << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");

  return 0;
}
```

...which had an interesting result: on my PC, with *g++* I got the following compile error:

```
$ g++ -g ./main.c && ./a.out
./main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.c:19:77: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const stringstream&’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>&’} from expression of type ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’
   19 |   func(std::stringstream("Hello World ") << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
./main.c:6:36: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void func(const stringstream&)’
    6 | void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

If I understand the compile error correctly, the value being passed to `func()` is of type `std::basic_ostream<char>` which cannot be implicitly cast to `std::stringstream`. Is this because the return-value of `operator<<` is type `std::basic_ostream`? (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)
The interesting part, though, is that at randomly-chosen online C++ compiler https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/, the same code compiles, however what gets printed to *stdout* is:

```
0(Success)d
```

...which seems to show the string "Hello World" being overwritten by the the value of `errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")"`
I presume this difference of behavior is due to different compilers, and I would like to understand if/why this is the case -- but this is tangential to the specific question asked here, and I may ask it as a separate, specific question.

tl;dr: in the following code, function `main()` invokes function `func()` by using an explicit local, named variable:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")";
  func(ss);

  return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ -g ./main.c && ./a.out
Hello World 0(Success)
```

...**is there a way to invoke function `func()` without the the caller using an explicit, named variable?**

---

Update: I tried the following based on an answer-as-comment:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func(std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");

  return 0;
}
```

...which resulted in this compile-error:

```
$ g++ -g ./main.c && ./a.out
./main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.c:46:81: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const stringstream&’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char>&’} from expression of type ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’
   46 |   func(std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
./main.c:6:36: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void func(const stringstream&)’
    6 | void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

...which looks the same as when I tried `func(std::stringstream("Hello World ") << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");`

---

Update: I tried the following based on an answer-as-comment:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func((std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")").str());

  return 0;
}
```

...which resulted in this compile error:

```
$ g++ -g ./main.c && ./a.out
./main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.c:11:90: error: ‘class std::basic_ostream<char>’ has no member named ‘str’
   11 |   func((std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")").str());
      |
```

Comment: `func(std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");`

Comment: @heapunderrun -- compile error...I will update my post with the attempt and corresponding compile error.

Comment: What verison of g++ do you have? What is the output of `g++ --version`? Ok, I can reproduce with gcc 11.1 https://godbolt.org/z/6eW6fThjf

Comment: @StoneThrow What error? I'm not getting any errors: https://godbolt.org/z/seqzb4xjv

Comment: @heapunderrun -- see the "Update" section (at the bottom) of my updated post. It appears to be the same error as my original trial workaround, which was using `func(std::stringstream("Hello World ") << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");`

Comment: `func(static_cast<std::stringstream&>(std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")"));`  works, but.... std::stringstream::operator<< returns a basic_ostream, why does never gcc accept it? Does it construct a new sstringstream from basic_ostream?

Comment: @KamilCuk - (just to answer explicitly even though you reproduced with `gcc 11.1`) I use `g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0` -- it is whatever Microsoft bundled with their Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There is no way to do this that isn't way less readable than just putting in the variable.

Comment: I see… I can reproduce the error with g++ 11.1, but not with g++ 11.2.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - :) I'm willing to accept that as an answer if you're willing to expand on it a little (I'm trying to learn C++ language nuances related to this issue). Like: what is a solution that is less readable than just putting in the variable? And I wonder if you could explain a bit about what is wrong with what I've tried so far...I'm not 100% sure I'm grokking the compile errors.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - based on some of the comments, it also appears there are issues related to compiler versions...if you/any willing answerer is knowledgeable about this, I'd like to understand that as well.

Comment: What about just passing a string like `func((std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")").str())`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious -- compile error...I will update my post with the attempt and corresponding compile error.

Comment: @KamilCuk - your solution using the explicit `static_cast` works, even with g++ 9.4.0 -- thank you. I don't know this with 100% certainty, but what it looks like to me is that `stringstream::operator<<` returns type `basic_ostream<char>` which is not explicitly down-cast to derived-class `stringstream` without the explicit `static_cast`. But it appears this is also a compiler-version-specific issue...not sure if this was considered a compiler bug and "fixed" in 11.2.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use a string instead of a stringstream:

```cpp
func(std::string("Hello World ") + std::to_string(errno) + "(" + strerror(errno) + ")");
```

...or possibly, if you don't mind one extra line elsewhere:

```cpp
using namespace std::literals;

// ...

func("Hello World "s + std::to_string(errno) + "(" + strerror(errno) + ")");
```

Either way, you would need to rewrite `func` to receive an `std::string` (or a `std::string const &`) instead of an `std::stringstream` (but given that all `func` is doing with it is calling `str()` to get a string, that doesn't seem like it should be a problem).

Another possibility would be to rewrite `func` to to be a variadic template:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
void func(Args&&... args) {    
    ((std::cout << std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    // or if you want writing to the stream to be atomic, write them
    // to a stringstream then write that to std::cout:
//    std::stringstream foo;
//    ((foo << std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
//    std::cout << foo.str();
}

int main() { 
    func("Hello World ", errno, " (", strerror(errno), ")");
}
```

...which produces the expected result:

```
Hello World 0 (Success)
```

Answer (score 2):

May be not what you are looking for, but sometimes it used this way:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace { // Just to hide from other modules
class mystream : public std::stringstream
{
public:
    ~mystream() {
        std::cout << str() << std::endl;
    }
};
}

mystream func() {
  return {};
}

int main() {
  func() << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")";

  return 0;
}
```

As a sidnote, C++ has its own mechanisms to handle `errno`, you can try to use it this way:

```
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class mystream : public std::stringstream
{
public:
    ~mystream() {
        std::cout << str() << std::endl;
    }
};

mystream func() {
  return {};
}

int main() {
  // Capture error for possible transmission and later processing
  std::error_code err{errno, std::system_category()};

  // You can compare it to platform-independent enum
  if (err == std::errc::invalid_argument)
    return 1;

  // You can print it
  func() << "Hello World " << err.value() << "(" << err.message() << ")";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very clever use of a temporary object and its destructor -- I like it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a user defined literal.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream operator ""_ss(const char* str, size_t size) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss.write(str, size);
  return ss;
}

void func(const std::stringstream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func("Hello World "_ss << errno << " (" << std::strerror(errno) << ")");
}

// Output:
// Hello World 0 (Success)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bn7sq97Wq

As for the compiler error in your second attempt

```
func((std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")").c_str());
//                                                                                     ^^^^^^^
//                                                                      Absolutely unnecessary:
func(std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");
```

It does not work until GCC 11.2. `std::basic_stringstream` inherits `std::basic_ostream` and the returned type of its `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<` is `basic_ostream&` that is not suitable for `const std::stringstream&`. The work around is the modified `func()`:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream operator ""_ss(const char* str, size_t size) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss.write(str, size);
  return ss;
}

void func(const std::ostream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.rdbuf() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func("Hello World "_ss << errno << " (" << std::strerror(errno) << ")");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/szqvrcbW8

Comment: With this solution, I again get the same compile error as my first workaround (`func(std::stringstream("Hello World ") << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");`) as well as my first "Update" (`func(std::stringstream{} << "Hello World " << errno << "(" << strerror(errno) << ")");`). The pattern seems to be that there is compiler/version-specific behavior at play here: with my _g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0_ any `stringstream` that further uses its `operator<<` returns a `basic_ostream` which can't be _implicitly_ downcast to a `stringstream` for `func()`'s arg.

Comment: My terminology is probably pretty bad -- I hope I was comprehensible with what I just said.

Comment: @StoneThrow see the updates